# Counting balls in a cover of a smooth curve

Tags: combinatorics, differential-geometry

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth curve and let $0<\delta <\mathrm{Length}(f)$.  How many balls of radius $\delta$ do I need to cover $f$?  In the case of a line I'm getting $\frac1{2\delta}$ but I don't know how to approach the general problem.  I'm guessing some variational approach.

Comment: Do you really want an exact count, or only show that $\lim_{\delta\to 0} n(\delta)\delta= \frac 12\operatorname{Length}(f)?$

Comment: Just a reasonable upper bound.  I guess $\frac{Length(f)}{2\delta}$ but I'm just not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, (the ceiling of) $Length/2\delta$ works.

Suppose throughout that $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^d$ is smooth, and let $$L=\int_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt.$$

> > **Theorem.** If  $N\ge\frac L{2\delta}$ is an integer then $N$ closed balls of radius $\delta$ suffice.

> > **Lemma.** If $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ then there exists $x\in[a,b]$ with $f([a,b])\subset \overline B\left(f(x),\frac12\int_a^b|f'|\right)$.

Proof of the Lemma: By contiuity there exists $x\in[a,b]$ with $$\int_a^x|f'|=\int_x^b|f'|=\frac12\int_a^b|f'|.$$If $t\in[a,x]$ then $|f(t)-f(x)|\le\int_a^x|f'|$; similarly if $t\in[x,b]$.

Proof of the Theorem: Since $\int_a^t|f'(s)|\,ds$ depends continuously on $t$ we may find $0=a_0<a_1<\dots<a_N=1$ with  $$\int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}}|f'(s)|\,ds=\frac L N\le2\delta.$$The Lemma shows that $f([a_j,a_{j+1}])\subset\overline B(f(x_j),\delta)$.